# PrimeNG p-calendar - ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError - howto handle

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have a problem with PrimeNG *p-calendar* component (Angular version: "~4.0.0"): I use it inside a p-dialog like this:

```
<p-dialog header="User Details" [(visible)]="displayDialog" [responsive]="true" showEffect="fade" [modal]="true">
    <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="dateOfBirth" [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar><span>{{dateOfBirth|date}}</span>
</p-dialog>
```

When user ***selects the value in calendar***, **it throws an error** in console log:

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: ''. Current value: '10'.
    at viewDebugError (:37885/libs/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8668) [angular]
```

But when I use '***inline***' option, **it works perfect**:

```
<p-dialog header="User Details" [(visible)]="displayDialog" [responsive]="true" showEffect="fade" [modal]="true">
    <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="dateOfBirth" [inline]="true"></p-calendar><span>{{dateOfBirth|date}}</span>
</p-dialog>
```

[image]

Here is the code of the component (trimmed a little):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,    
    selector: 'user-details',
    templateUrl: './user-details.html'  
})

export class UserDetailComponent {     
    dateOfBirth: Date;

    constructor(
       private route: ActivatedRoute,
       private router: Router
    ) {}

    onDateSelect(value: Date) {
        console.log("onDateSelect");
    }

    onBlur(value: Date) {
        console.log("onBlur");
    }
}
```

Has anyone got any ideas about how to handle this issue? I appreciate your try, anyway, Thanks!

---

I've created a [plunker p-calendar issue](https://embed.plnkr.co/ec5RQr/) project to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Is this all relevant code that you posted?

Comment: actually, the code is more complicated, I trimmed it to avoid redundant complexity in this post. If the above information is not enough, I'll try to post the whole code on some shared resource.

Comment: I've created a plunker project for this issue, please, check the link at the end of the post. Thanks!

Comment: Update primeng and the problem will go away

Comment: thank you so much! the solution was so simple: I've updated primeng up to "4.0.0-rc.2" version in my project, and now it works well